# Azure, Quickstart templates, xp config error: Microsoft.Insights/Components/CurrentBillingFeatures failed with message code:BadRequest

Tags: azure

I am currently using the Azure Quickstart templates found on Sitecore's Github page.

https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/

I've successfully used these before, with both xp0 and xp configurations, however that was a couple of months ago.
I've pulled down the latest, but noticed that there weren't any changes from the 8.2.3 and 8.2.4 templates from when I last used them.

I am now attempting to use the Azure Toolkit, v1.1, which I also previously used successfully, and have all the appropriate packages and permissions for things in my Azure storage account. I also have a lot of credits remaining on my Azure account, so no issue there.... However....

When I go to run

```
$Name = "myspecialdeployment"

Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment -Location "East US" -Name $Name -ArmTemplateUrl "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/.../azuredeploy.json" -ArmParametersPath "D:\SitecoreAzure\xp\azuredeploy.parameters.8.2.4.json" -LicenseXmlPath "D:\_Sitecores\license.xml" -SetKeyValue @{ "deploymentId" = $Name } -Verbose
```

I first see an error

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 12:11:39 PM - Resource
>   Microsoft.Insights/Components/CurrentBillingFeatures
>   'myspecialdeployment-ai/myspecialdeployment-ai-pp' failed with message
>   '{ "code": "BadRequest", "message": "Bad Request", "innererror": {
>   "diagnosticcontext": "fda85feb-f0d3-43f2-a15f-73076378d052", "time":
>   "2017-09-09T16:11:36.9342218Z" } }' At
>   D:_Sitecores_Azure\Toolkits\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1 rev
>   170509\Tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:115 char:35
>   + ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Na...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
>   loymentCmdlet

The deployment continues....

I then see the deployment fail about 20 minutes later with...

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 12:22:49 PM - Template output
>   evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed.
>   Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. At
>   D:_Sitecores_Azure\Toolkits\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1 rev
>   170509\Tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:115 char:35
>   + ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
>   loymentCmdlet
>
> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 12:22:49 PM - Template output
>   evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed.
>   Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. At
>   D:_Sitecores_Azure\Toolkits\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1 rev
>   170509\Tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:115 char:35
>   + ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
>   loymentCmdlet New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 12:22:54 PM -
>   Resource Microsoft.Resources/deployments
>   'myspecialdeployment-infrastructure' failed with message '{ "status":
>   "Failed", "error": { "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure", "message":
>   "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state
>   'Failed'.", "details": [ { "code": "DeploymentFailed", "message": "At
>   least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment
>   operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage
>   details.", "details": [ { "code": "BadRequest", "message": "{\r\n
>   \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n \"message\": \"Bad Request\",\r\n
>   \"innererror\": {\r\n \"diagnosticcontext\":
>   \"fda85feb-f0d3-43f2-a15f-73076378d052\",\r\n \"time\":
>   \"2017-09-09T16:11:36.9342218Z\"\r\n }\r\n}" } ] } ] } }'

As I said.....I've had this working previously....and all URLs are correct and accessible.
Further more, while the deployment says ProvisioningState       : Failed, I still see things like the initial Application Insights App Service available in the Resource Group....along with all the other App Services....just the site doesn't work.

Has something changed with Microsoft's billing and resource availability for some of these App Services (like ApplicationInsights)?

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but have you checked that all required parameters (in the parameters.xml file) are set correctly in the ARM templates?

Comment: Only XP0 is deployed successfully without a glitch. All other topologies are experiencing the same error. I'm sure Sean and I were not the only ones experiencing this issue. Even with the use of the Marketplace, the same error is encountered. I doubt that this is a case of a missed requirement in the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you would like to install it using your MSDN subscription.

> Azure monthly credits for Visual Studio subscribers cannot be used
>   towards Application Insights purchases. As a result, this resource is
>   limited to the Basic pricing plan and can only collect up to 32.3 MB
>   of data per day. To enable the collection of additional data and the
>   use of advanced features, you must remove the spending limit from this
>   Azure subscription.

To be able to run this with your Visual Studio Enterprise subscription, you can remove the following from the nested/infrastructure.json file.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/Components/CurrentBillingFeatures",
  "name": "[concat(variables('appInsightsNameTidy'), '/', variables('appInsightsPricePlanTidy'))]",
  "location": "[parameters('applicationInsightsLocation')]",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('appInsightsApiVersion')]",
  "properties": {
    "CurrentBillingFeatures": "[parameters('resourceSizes').ApplicationInsightsPricePlan.CurrentBillingFeatures]",
    "DataVolumeCap": {
    "Cap": "[parameters('resourceSizes').ApplicationInsightsPricePlan.DataVolumeCap.Cap]"
    }
  },
 "dependsOn": [
  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/Components', variables('appInsightsNameTidy'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
  "provider": "[variables('sitecoreTags').provider]"
  } 
}
```

For more details see: https://github.com/ivanbuzyka/Sitecore.SitecoreOnAzure.Articles/wiki/Application-Insights-issues-when-using-MSDN,-MPN-Azure-subscription